# How do I use a Do-While loop in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, while-loop

I don't know how to add the string "Knockout." so that it shows at the end of the Do While loop output.

I've tried adding `Knockout` to `lblResult.Text = ""`, which results in a building error.

I've tried reversing lblResult.Text with LP, but the numbers ended up going in descending order which I didn't want.
lblResult.Text = lblResult.Text & LP & " "

```vb
   Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        Dim LP As Integer

        LP = 1
        lblResult.Text = "" 'why is this line needed? what happens whne you remove it and click on LP1 button twice.

        Do While (LP < 11)

            lblResult.Text = lblResult.Text & LP & " "
            LP = LP + 1
        Loop

    End Sub
```

(v) Have a button, "Knock Out", which when clicked will print:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 KnockOut. 
Must use a while loop. Display the result in Label. Write code to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Do-While` loop:

1. Checks that `LP` is less than 11
2. Adds (more accurately, [contatenates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation)) the value of `LP`, and a  (space character), to the `lblResult.Text` Sting property.
3. Adds 1 to `LP`
4. Returns to the start of the loop.

So, by the time your loop finishes, you know that:

- `LP` == 10
- `lblResult.text` == '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10'

So, when your loop ends, you know that you can add `Knockout` to the end of `lblResult.text` to meet your requirement.

How would you add additional text *after* your loop?

Good luck with your [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 0):

> why is this line needed? what happens whne you remove it and click on LP1 button twice.

It just clears your label assigning empty string to `Text` property of the label.

If you remove this line, the text won't be cleared and then, if you press the button twice, you label would containt two series of numbers from 1 to 10:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Further, it just adds consecutive numbers to this label creating text `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` just like you want it.

At the end you just need to add line

```
lblResult.Text = lblResult.Text & "Knockout"
```

Answer (score 0):

We have &= and += that shortens the code a bit. Try it and see.

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim LP = 1
    Label1.Text = ""
    Do While (LP < 11)
        Label1.Text &= LP.ToString & " "
        LP += 1
    Loop
    Label1.Text &= " Knockout"
End Sub
```